# graph algorithms: reachability from adjacency map

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a dependency graph that I have represented as a `Map<Node, Collection<Node>>` (in Java-speak, or `f(Node n) -> Collection[Node]` as a function; this is a mapping from a given node `n` to a collection of nodes that depend on `n`). The graph is potentially cyclic*.

Given a list `badlist` of nodes, I would like to solve a [*reachability problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability): i.e. generate a `Map<Node, Set<Node>> badmap` that represents a mapping from each node N in the list `badlist` to a set of nodes which includes N or other node that transitively depends on it.

Example:

```
(x -> y means node y depends on node x)
n1 -> n2
n2 -> n3
n3 -> n1
n3 -> n5
n4 -> n2
n4 -> n5
n6 -> n1
n7 -> n1
```

This can be represented as the adjacency map `{n1: [n2], n2: [n3], n3: [n1, n5], n4: [n2, n5], n6: [n1], n7: [n1]}`.

If `badlist = [n4, n5, n1]` then I expect to get `badmap = {n4: [n4, n2, n3, n1, n5], n5: [n5], n1: [n1, n2, n3, n5]}`.

I'm floundering with finding graph algorithm references online, so if anyone could point me at an efficient algorithm description for reachability, I'd appreciate it. (An example of something that is *not* helpful to me is http://www.cs.fit.edu/~wds/classes/cse5081/reach/reach.html since that algorithm is to determine whether a specific node A is reachable from a specific node B.)

*cyclic: if you're curious, it's because it represents C/C++ types, and structures can have members which are pointers to the structure in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python:

```
def reachable(graph, badlist):
    badmap = {}
    for root in badlist:
        stack = [root]
        visited = set()
        while stack:
            v = stack.pop()
            if v in visited: continue
            stack.extend(graph[v])
            visited.add(v)
        badmap[root] = visited
    return badmap
```

Comment: ok, that's pretty simple. For some reason I got hung up on the fact that you have to re-execute the `for root in badlist` loop without benefit of the knowledge gained on previous executions of the loop. So maybe it's possible to optimize for speed... but what you have is pretty simple.

Comment: @Jason This is asymptotically optimal for graphs of bounded in-degree (i.e., number of different structure types referenced by a structure). I'd be surprised if the bottleneck weren't elsewhere.

Comment: @Jason: If you want to optimize that algorithm for speed, put the mark bit in the vertex itself rather than looking it up in an external `visited` set.

Answer (score 2):

here's what I ended up using, based on @quaint's answer:

(requires a few Guava classes for convenience)

```
static public <T> Set<T> findDependencies(
        T rootNode, 
        Multimap<T, T> dependencyGraph)
{
    Set<T> dependencies = Sets.newHashSet();
    LinkedList<T> todo = Lists.newLinkedList();
    for (T node = rootNode; node != null; node = todo.poll())
    {
        if (dependencies.contains(node))
            continue;
        dependencies.add(node);
        Collection<T> directDependencies = 
                dependencyGraph.get(node);
        if (directDependencies != null)
        todo.addAll(directDependencies);
    }
    return dependencies;
}
static public <T> Multimap<T,T> findDependencies(
        Iterable<T> rootNodes, 
        Multimap<T, T> dependencyGraph)
{
    Multimap<T, T> dependencies = HashMultimap.create();
    for (T rootNode : rootNodes)
        dependencies.putAll(rootNode, 
                findDependencies(rootNode, dependencyGraph));
    return dependencies;
}
static public void testDependencyFinder()
{
    Multimap<Integer, Integer> dependencyGraph = 
            HashMultimap.create();
    dependencyGraph.put(1, 2);
    dependencyGraph.put(2, 3);
    dependencyGraph.put(3, 1);
    dependencyGraph.put(3, 5);
    dependencyGraph.put(4, 2);
    dependencyGraph.put(4, 5);
    dependencyGraph.put(6, 1);
    dependencyGraph.put(7, 1);
    Multimap<Integer, Integer> dependencies = 
            findDependencies(ImmutableList.of(4, 5, 1), dependencyGraph);
    System.out.println(dependencies);
    // prints {1=[1, 2, 3, 5], 4=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5=[5]}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You maybe should build a **reachability matrix** from your adjacency list for fast searches. I just found the paper [Course Notes for CS336: Graph Theory - Jayadev Misra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/misra/Classes.dir/ClassNotes.dir/Graphs.pdf)
 which describes how to build the reachability matrix from a adjacency matrix.

If `A` is your adjacency matrix, the reachability matrix would be `R = A + A² + ... + A^n` where `n` is the number of nodes in the graph. `A², A³, ...` can be calculated by:

- `A² = A x A`
- `A³ = A x A²`
- ...

For the matrix multiplication the *logical or* is used in place of `+` and the *logical and* is used in place of `x`. The complexity is O(n^4).

Comment: +1 for interestingness, but my `badlist` is a very small number of nodes compared to the total # of nodes in the graph (badlist typically has size 4-10, whereas total # of nodes is in the tens of thousands), so I'm not sure that's either efficient or easy to implement for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary depth-first search or breadth-first search will do the trick: execute it once for each bad node.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working Java solution:

```
// build the example graph
Map<Node, Collection<Node>> graph = new HashMap<Node, Collection<Node>>();
graph.put(n1, Arrays.asList(new Node[] {n2}));
graph.put(n2, Arrays.asList(new Node[] {n3}));
graph.put(n3, Arrays.asList(new Node[] {n1, n5}));
graph.put(n4, Arrays.asList(new Node[] {n2, n5}));
graph.put(n5, Arrays.asList(new Node[] {}));
graph.put(n6, Arrays.asList(new Node[] {n1}));
graph.put(n7, Arrays.asList(new Node[] {n1}));

// compute the badmap
Node[] badlist = {n4, n5, n1};
Map<Node, Collection<Node>> badmap = new HashMap<Node, Collection<Node>>();

for(Node bad : badlist) {
    Stack<Node> toExplore = new Stack<Node>();
    toExplore.push(bad);
    Collection<Node> reachable = new HashSet<Node>(toExplore);
    while(toExplore.size() > 0) {
        Node aNode = toExplore.pop();
        for(Node n : graph.get(aNode)) {
            if(! reachable.contains(n)) {
                reachable.add(n);
                toExplore.push(n);
            }
        }
    }

    badmap.put(bad, reachable);
}

System.out.println(badmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like with Christian Ammer, you take for `A` the adjacency matrix and use Boolean arithmetic, when doing the following, where `I` is the identity matrix.

```
    B = A + I;
    C = B * B;
    while (B != C) {
        B = C;
        C = B * B;
    }
    return B;
```

Furthermore, standard matrix multiplication (both arithmetical and logical) is `O(n^3)`, not `O(n^2)`. But if `n <= 64`, you can sort of get rid of one factor `n`, because you can do 64 bits in parallel on nowadays 64 bits machines. For larger graphs, 64 bits parallelism is useful, too, but shader techniques might even be better.

EDIT: one can do 128 bits in parallel with SSE instructions, with AVX even more.